# Unable to find .gitconfig in old Git commits

Tags: git, git-config

I noticed a moment ago that my **.gitconfig** -file was public at my repo. It contains my secret tokens.

I `git-add -u` the file and committed. I am not sure whether this command removes the file from the previous commits too.

I want to be sure and search the file in my previous commits such that there is no such a file in my history.

**How can you search the file in previous commits?**

---

I run

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm .gitconfig' master     # Thanks to Greg!
```

I get

```
Rewrite 84dabfa2ea195ce9aad0309216858b302150017c (1/25)rm: .gitconfig: No such file or directory
tree filter failed: rm .gitconfig
```

The error message suggests me that I do not have the file at my commit history.

**Is there any way to search the file in my commit history** such that I do not need to run the removal to see that I do not have the file in my commit history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f .gitconfig' master
```

Note the `-f`.

**Long answer:**

`rm` would return a non-zero return code when file does not exist. `filter-branch` think this is an error and stop the rewrite. Adding `-f` avoid this.

**Note:**

There is an alternative command:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .gitconfig' master
```

which is MUCH faster. This command is documented in the EXAMPLE section of the man page.

Comment: @J-16: Both your commands give me the same error message as in my question. This suggests me that I have removed the file by accident by some command already. --- Do you know how you can search .gitconfig in Git's history such that I can be sure that there is no such file?

Comment: just `git log .gitconfig` should show the history.  NOTE:   .git/config (and anything under .git/) is *NOT* versioned, only .gitconfig.

Comment: @J-16: I get the info that the commits 57d6 and 0d97 contain my secret tokens. (1) How can I see these commits? (2) How can I remove these .gitconfig files from these commits?

Comment: @J-16: Your last command gives me the following warning although I have .gitconfig -files in my history: Cannot rewrite branch(es) with a dirty working directory.

Comment: "dirty working directory" means you have uncommitted works..  Run `git status` and commit (or reset) them.

Answer (score 4):

To remove a file from all past Git history, you will need to rewrite all past commits using something like [`git filter-branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-filter-branch.html). However, doing this makes your new tree unmergeable with all past trees, so do this with care.

Comment: I would like to play with the Git -files in /tmp. --- I played unsuccessfully with them after I copied .git to /tmp. --- This suggests me that I need to copy all files to /tmp with .git. --- @ How would you make a 2nd copy such that you can test the command?

Comment: You can clone a repository with "git clone". Anything you do to the cloned repository does not affect the original repository (unless you push your changes, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Reset all ewvisions in repository to global defaults (.gitconfig).

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="`git config --get user.name`";GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="`git config --get user.name`";GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="git config --get user.email";GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="`git config --get user.email`";git commit-tree "$@";' HEAD
```